# Make a bar-chart in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with dishes and scores, but when i try to make a bar-chart i get the same error message everytime.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("https://gitlab.stud.iie.ntnu.no/nilstesd/python-big-data/raw/master/data/dishes.csv", sep=";", encoding="utf-8")
print(df.head())


df = df.groupby(['Dish']).mean()
df = df.mean(['Dish']).values
df = df.mean(['Score']).values


plt.figure(figsize = (8,6), dpi = 72)
plt.xlabel('Dish')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.title('Dishes')
ax = plt.gca()
colors= ['r', 'b']
df.plot(kind='bar',color=colors, alpha=0.75, ax=ax)
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', linewidth=1.0)
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor')
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list

Comment: `df = df.groupby(['Dish']).mean()` `df = df.mean(['Dish']).values` `df = df.mean(['Score']).values` is not going to work.

Comment: Remove `df = df.mean(['Dish']).values` and `df = df.mean(['Score']).values` and that will be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reassign each column of the groupby object to itself: the lines `df = df.mean(['Dish']).values` and `df = df.mean(['Score']).values` should be removed as pointed out in the comments by @Henry Ecker and @azro

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("https://gitlab.stud.iie.ntnu.no/nilstesd/python-big-data/raw/master/data/dishes.csv", sep=";", encoding="utf-8")
print(df.head())

df = df.groupby(['Dish']).mean()

plt.figure(figsize = (8,6), dpi = 72)
plt.xlabel('Dish')
plt.ylabel('Score')
plt.title('Dishes')
ax = plt.gca()
colors= ['r', 'b']
df.plot(kind='bar',color=colors, alpha=0.75, ax=ax)
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', linewidth=1.0)
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do I make the bar-chart come up, for me there is only a list with an index of 2 where there is only written r, b

Comment: Did you run the line `plt.show()`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I use Spyder, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Maybe, I am not too familiar with this IDE. You can also save the plot as a .png file and view it: `plt.savefig("bar.png")`

Comment: Then I only get a white image.